# getOccupation() in GooglePlus app Android always returning null

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus-domains

I am trying to access profile's occupation using getOccupation() using Plus Domain. This is always returning null, although it is set as public in the Google plus profile. I have tried with different scopes but with no avail. Are you people able to retrieve occupation of the profile correctly? Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Person mePerson;

```
mePerson = plusDomains.people().get("me").execute();
txtOccupation.setText(txtOccupation+ "\n "+mePerson.getOccupation());
```